# Rewriting a function to read json file using class

Tags: python, json, class

I'm writing a code based on json file that allows the user choose the file in the beginning of the program I wrote the following function to read the file,

```
file_name = input("Which .json file do you want to open? ")
def read_json_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as json_file:
        weather = js.load(json_file)
    return weather
```

Later, I was advised to rewrite the code using class to get better structure. Since I'm not very familiar with it, I got help to rewrite it like this

```
class Weather_data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = input("Which .json file do you want to open? ")

    def read_json_file(self):
        with open(self.file_name) as json_file:
            weather = js.load(json_file)
        return weather
```

But instead of returning the whole file, is there any way i can only return specific parts of the json file?
For example

```
for i in range(len(weather['date'])):
   date = weather['value'][i]['date']
   value = weather['value'][i]['value']
```

i.e only these 2 parts, but i want to be able to access those using my defined class!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, put the file name input into the **init** of the class so when you create an instance it asks for the json file and sets it as an attribute of the class instance.

See here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

example:

```
class Weather_data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = input("Which .json file do you want to open? ")

    def read_json_file(self):
        with open(self.file_name) as json_file:
            weather = js.load(json_file)
        return weather
```

You could also set the weather to be a attribute of the class , i.e `self.weather=js.load(json_file)`
and then access it with the instance of your class.

EDIT:

Since you edited your question. You can add a new attribute for each of the things you want to access and then access it via the class instance.

```
def read_json_file(self):
    with open(self.file_name) as json_file:
        self.weather = js.load(json_file)
    self.value=self.weather['value'] #or whatever you want
```

Then access via:

```
weather_data=Weather_data() #instance of the class, will prompt for json file
weather_data.read_json_file() #runs the method
print(weather_data.value) #would print it
```